# ¿Cómo evitar que las definiciones en cabeceras se copien en cada UdT? (Unidad de Traducción)

Tags: c++

Tengo una función de definida en una cabecera que es llamada en la propia cabecera:

`a.hpp`

```
namespace AAAAA
{

namespace
{

static int init() { std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << '\n'; return 42; }
//         ^^^^^^ <--- Definida en cabecera.

}

void f();

static int i = init();
//             ^^^^^^ <--- Llamada en cabecera.
}
```

La cabecera `a.hpp` se incluye en dos archivos:

`a.cpp`

```
#include "a.hpp" // Contiene la definición y llamada a 'init()'

#include <iostream>

namespace AAAAA
{

void f()
{
    std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << " : " << i << '\n';
}

}
```

`main.cpp`

```
#include "a.hpp" // Contiene la definición y llamada a 'init()'
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    AAAAA::f();
    return 0;
}
```

Al ejecutar el programa obtengo la siguiente salida:

> ```
> int AAAAA::(anonymous namespace)::init()
> int AAAAA::(anonymous namespace)::init()
> void AAAAA::f() : 42
> ```

Se ha llamado dos veces a `init`, una desde la UdT de `main` y otra desde la UdT de `a`, esta múltiple llamada a la función se repite por cada UdT añadida en que se incluya `a.hpp`:

`b.hpp`

```
namespace BBBBB
{

void f();

}
```

`b.cpp`

```
#include "b.hpp"
#include "a.hpp" // Contiene la definición y llamada a 'init()'

#include <iostream>

namespace BBBBB
{

void f()
{
    std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << " : " << AAAAA::i << '\n';
}

}
```

`main.cpp`

```
#include "a.hpp"
#include "b.hpp"

#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    AAAAA::f();
    BBBBB::f();
    return 0;
}
```

La nueva salida con los cambios anteriores:

> ```
> int AAAAA::(anonymous namespace)::init()
> int AAAAA::(anonymous namespace)::init()
> int AAAAA::(anonymous namespace)::init()
> void AAAAA::f() : 42
> void BBBBB::f() : 42
> ```

Cada UdT en que se incluya `a.hpp` obtiene una copia de `AAAAA::i` (pese a que `AAAAA::i` es `static`) por lo tanto cada una hace una llamada a `init`.

¿**Cómo puedo evitar que se haga una copia de `AAAAA::i` en cada UdT y en consecuencia se llame `init` por cada copia de dicha variable?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usa `extern`.

---

La palabra clave `extern` indica que de una declaración existe una única definición en algún punto:

`a.hpp`

```
namespace AAAAA
{

void f();

extern int i; // 'i' existe, pero será definida en otro sitio.

}
```

`a.cpp`

```
namespace AAAAA
{

int init() { std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << '\n'; return 42; }

void f()
{
    std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << " : " << &i << ' ' << i << '\n';
}

int i = init(); // 'i' se define aquí.

}
```

Con este cambio en `a.hpp` y `a.cpp`, tu salida será:

> ```
> int AAAAA::init()
> void AAAAA::f() : 42
> void BBBBB::f() : 42
> ```

Con la ventaja de no tener que exponer `init` en el archivo de cabecera.

Answer (score 1):

Desde C++17 alternativamente a la [solución](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/297829/143017) de [PaperBirdMaster](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/2742/paperbirdmaster) se puede utilizar `inline`:

```
a.hpp:

namespace AAAAA
{
    inline int init () { return 42; }
    inline int i = init();
}
```

Nota que ya no tenemos el namespace anónimo. Eso es bueno si solo tienes la cabecera; si tambien exista un fichero cpp, yo prefería la solucion de PaperBirdMaster.